# How to select a specific radio button using driver.find_element() with multiple attributes?

Tags: python, select, radio-button

[I am trying to select the radio button "Higher" as shown in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiYbn.png)

Here is the full code for the tree containing that element.

```
<tr>
          <td class="label">
            <label for="radio_68007_control_group" id="radio_68007_control_group_label">
              Tie-break Rule
            </label>
          </td>
          <td class="control">
            <table id="radio_68007_control_group" cellpadding="0" aria-labelledby="radio_68007_control_group_label" cellspacing="0" class="input radio" role="radiogroup">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td class="radio">
                    <span class="radio">
                    </span>
                    <input type="radio" name="Tie.45.break_Rule" value="-1" id="radio_68007_control" aria-labelledby="radio_68007_control_group_label labelradio_68007_control" label="Tie-break Rule" validationid="Tie.45.break_Rule_validation_00003" validation="['exactselected=1']">
                  </td>
                  <td class="breakword radiolabel">
                    <label for="radio_68007_control" id="labelradio_68007_control">
                      Lower
                    </label>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="radio">
                    <span class="radio">
                    </span>
                    <input type="radio" name="Tie.45.break_Rule" value="1" id="radio_68008_control" aria-labelledby="radio_68007_control_group_label labelradio_68008_control" checked="checked">
                  </td>
                  <td class="breakword radiolabel">
                    <label for="radio_68008_control" id="labelradio_68008_control">
                      Higher
                    </label>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
```

Is it possible to search for the input by type, name, and value attributes at the same time and then select the input using driver.find_element(By.NAME,'').click(). I'm wondering because as you can see from the above code, there are multiple inputs within this element and within the DOM with the same name "Tie.45.break_Rule" so I would like to be able to specify the exact one I need to click at the time.

Here is the XPATH for the "Higher" radio button:

```
//*[@id="radio_68008_control"]
```

^This doesn't seem like a good choice to use because the numeric value that is included in the id for the element changes every time the code is run and I intend to use it for several different projects not at the same time (hence why I want to use driver.find_element(By.NAME,''))

I have tried to do this via driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'').click() using the full xPath for that element since that doesn't seem to change over time/is more generic, but that did not work.

Here is the full xPath for the "Higher" radio button:

```
/html/body/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[7]/div[2]/div[8]/div[2]/div/form/table/tbody[2]/tr[6]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/input
```

^This caused the code to fail with a "NoSuchElementException" error message